# Java Matcher class with regex and loop

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, pattern-matching

```
    String sCurrentLine;    
    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));

 while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {

    Pattern pattern  = Pattern.compile(".*?unregistKey\\(tvKey\\.(.*?)\\);");
    Matcher m= pattern.matcher(sCurrentLine);
            if(m.matches()) {
                String abc = m.group(1) ;
                System.out.println ("aaaaaaaaaaaaaa" + abc.toString());
             }                  
 }
```

Why this code is looping more than 1 time. 
I checked this call to this code but its coming only 1 time.

o/p is N times like this:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaKEY_1
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaKEY_2
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaKEY_3
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaKEY_CH_UP
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaKEY_PANEL_CH_UP
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaKEY_CH_DOWN
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaKEY_1
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaKEY_2
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaKEY_3
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaKEY_CH_UP
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaKEY_PANEL_CH_UP
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaKEY_CH_DOWN
```

Comment: There is a loop to read file line by line in your code. The println inside only execute once for each line in which a match is found.

Comment: This is inside a method in which i pass path variable which is file path. Doing this job on flat file. I think there is a problen in while loop but new to java so not able to find exact place

Comment: Thanks for help got my problem i will put the answer over here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will see this output only when the input file contains the same pattern several times (i.e. there are several lines that contain `KEY_1`, etc).

Comment: The line doesn't have to be the same, only need to have the same format that matches the regex. The output shows that the lines are different.

Comment: What I meant is that the file contains `KEY_1` several times. Improved my wording.

Comment: Oh. So that's what you meant.